# Real time database like HBase for .Net applications

Tags: .net, hbase

Is there a free real time database like HBase for .Net applications?

Many thanks,

Comment: Why can't you use HBase in a .NET application?

Comment: Hi Eran, what are the steps required in order to do so. HBase API are written in Java and generally installed in Linux hence will this be an intricate process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HBase from .NET.
HBase has a Thrift API and you can generate a .NET client for that.

If you'll ever require some more advanced calls than what the Thrift API exposes you can write your own Thrift service in Java (or fork and modify the existing one) and call it from .NET.

Besides Thrift it alo has a REST and Avro API which you can also call from .NET

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, are there any tutorials or examples of these APis being used by a C# application?

Answer (score 1):

As Eran said you can use HBase from .NET with the Thrift API, however you'd have problems with newer capabilities like coporcessors (writing UDFs and triggers that run inside HBase) which are coming in the next releases

You may want to look at MongoDB which has [relatively good .NET interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Community+Projects)

Oh, and if you're running in Azure than TableStorage is a nice NoSql option from MS itself

Comment: Thanks, buts isnt MS charging for Azure service

Comment: Yes - but if you're already using it for other stuff the price for TableStorage is negligible. MongoDB is free